# Amount of rain in July in Nicaragua?

Tags: international-travel, weather-and-climate, nicaragua

I am looking to book a 1 week yoga retreat in Nicaragua, but will it be raining all the time? What's the weather like in Nicaragua this time of year?

Comment: In this context _good_ means _not raining_? Or does _good_ means something else?

Comment: I have been through Nicaragua in the summer and it rains, but only for a short amount of time.  It's bloody hot and if you are not used to it or near the Atlantic breeze, the heat will be oppressive.  But otherwise your question is formed such that people must rely upon opinion.  Close voting as 'opinion based'

Comment: I'm not sure you'll really tell the difference between raining and not raining ... your clothing will be soaked in either case.:)

Comment: take a look at https://weatherspark.com/averages/32620/Managua-Nicaragua - if this reopens I will add an answer

Comment: After three seconds on Google I found http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geography_of_Nicaragua#Rainfall

Comment: It will depend on where you are: the western and eastern lowlands and the highlands have significantly different climates.

Comment: @KateGregory this did reopen! Still interested in writing an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you will be visiting the capital, [Managua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managua), July actually seems the worst time to visit, as it's in the middle of the rainy season. Other areas of the country probably won't be sunny as well.

[image]